# Selenium compatibility

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, internet-explorer-driver

I'm facing lots of issues in finding out compatibility for Selenium driver, chrome driver & IE driver with the latest versions (installed in my system) of chrome and IE browsers. I've installed 80.0.3987.106 chrome driver to support my Chrome browser (80). But, its extremely flaky. It keeps on failing all the tests. I tried various other options ( Chromeoptions), but nothing works. Can someone suggest which chrome browser should I use ( and where to download it) and whats the compatible selenium driver and Chrome driver ? Same thing for IE and Firefox, if possible.  Really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Explore this page for chromedriver compatible to your locally installed browser version. https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: And for IE, explore this link . https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

Comment: Thx. As I mentioned in my original comment, I already tried the suggested driver (80.0.3987.106$ and browser (80). But, most tests fail. I’m asking for the version of browser and driver which most of you are using in 2020. I also need to know the site where I can download the older versions (if required) without any risk. Thank you.

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 80.0.3987.116  with selenium 3.141.59 version maven dependency